# codeigniter Caching Driver function clean() not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using file based caching in codeigniter Its sets cache successfully but it fails to clean it.

**code**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Tm extends CI_Controller {

public function index(){

    $this->load->driver('cache');

    if ($foo = $this->cache->file->get('foo2'))
        echo $foo.'<br />';
    else
        {
        echo 'Saving to the cache!<br />';
        $foo = 'foobarbaz! :D';
        $this->cache->file->save('foo2', $foo, 60);
        }
    if($this->cache->clean())
        echo "clearing cache ";
    else
        echo "Error clearing cache ";
    }
    
}
```

the first output :

> Saving to the cache!
>
> clearing cache

when i refresh it

> foobarbaz! :D
>
> clearing cache

It looks like `$this->cache->clean()` function always return **true** also when it is failed

Comment: Why would that be considered a failure?

Comment: if $this->cache->clean() works fine the out put when i refresh the page is must be same as the first out put. Go through the code.

Comment: I see ... does `$this->cache->file->delete('foo2')` return TRUE as well?

Answer (score 0):

While editing my own last comment, I realized that I had done the exact same mistake as you - missing `->file` on the `clear()` call.

The default adapter for the Cache class is 'dummy' and you didn't pass a new one to the initializer, so calling `$this->cache->clear()` would try to call `$this->cache->dummy->clear()` instead of `$this->cache->file->clear()`.

You'll have to either explicitly call `$this->cache->file->clear()` or do this when loading the library:

```
$this->load->library('cache', array('adapter' => 'file'));
```

Edit:

`CI_Cache_file` would still return TRUE if it's not able to delete any or all files withing the cache path. It simply calls the `delete_files()` file helper, which doesn't check the return values of `unlink()`. You can't work around that as there are no transactions for file deletes as there are in databases.